# How can I download android source code with TortoiseGit

Tags: git, android, tortoise-git

How can I download android source code with TortoiseGit? [Here](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) it is explained using `Repo` but I use TortoiseGit.

**EDIT1**
@heavyd, If I do that I get this error(and my local folder is deleted!). I also tried `"D:\android-source\"` as local folder but still the same error.(I try those steps inside `"D:\android-source\"` folder):

```
git.exe clone  --progress -v  "git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git" "D:\android-source\manifest"

Cloning into D:\android-source\manifest...
android.git.kernel.org[0: 149.20.4.77]: errno=No such file or directory
fatal: unable to connect a socket (No such file or directory)
```

**EDIT2**
ok, it seems that android.git.kernel.org is down for a month! See: http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/bd008b9fc907250b/f9bb28b02a32e8dc?lnk=gst&q=kernel.org#f9bb28b02a32e8dc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Git server at `android.git.kernel.org` has been temporarily taken down at Google's request, due to the recent Kernel.org break-in.

In the mean time, you can use the mirror hosted by Github:

```
git clone git://github.com/android/platform_manifest.git manifest
```

See https://github.com/android for the list of all repositories.

When kernel.org goes back up, all you'll need to do is `git remote set-url <x>` to switch back to the master repository.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the folder where you would like to downloaded source to be stored.
2. Right-click and select "Git Clone"
3. Enter the URL: git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git
4. Click OK

After that, its just normal Git.  Pull to update your local tree with the latest from the server, create and checkout branches, etc.

Comment: If I do that, I get an error. See my edit.Any ideas?

Comment: could it be company firewall, or antivirus?

Comment: ok, it seems that android.git.kernel.org is down for a month! See: http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/bd008b9fc907250b/f9bb28b02a32e8dc?lnk=gst&q=kernel.org#f9bb28b02a32e8dc